# How do I change the player's image if the player collides with a sprite

Tags: python, windows, image, pygame, sprite

I made the first level of a game. The second level I was thinking could be that when the player collides or touches a car the current player's image would disappear and the player's new image would be the car, just as it would look like the player is inside and driving the car. Can the car also have the same functions and controls like the player has like left, right, up, down, etc... How do I change the players image and still get the same controls as the player? I have made a class for the car and the player but I don't know what to do next. Any help will be appreciated. Python 2.6, Pygame sprites, windows 7.

Here is the car's class.

```
class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
change_x = 0
change_y = 0
movingPlatform_list = None
frame_since_collision = 0

def __init__(self, color, width, height):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image.fill(aqua)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def update(self, player, block_list, movingPlatform_list):
    # Move left/right
    self.rect.x += self.change_x

    # See if we hit anything
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, block_list, False)
    movingPlatform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, movingPlatform_list, False)

    for block in block_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = block.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = block.rect.right

    for movingPlatform in movingPlatform_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = movingPlatform.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = movingPlatform.rect.right

    # Move up/down
    self.rect.y += self.change_y

    # Check and see if we hit anything
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, block_list, False)
    movingPlatform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, movingPlatform_list, False)

    for block in block_hit_list:

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
        else:
            self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

    for movingPlatform in movingPlatform_hit_list:

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = movingPlatform.rect.top
        else:
            self.rect.top = movingPlatform.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

        self.rect.x += movingPlatform.change_x

    # Increment frame counter
    self.frame_since_collision += 1

# Calculate effect of gravity.
def calc_grav(self):
    self.change_y += .35

    # See if we are on the ground.
    if self.rect.y >= 485 and self.change_y >= 0:
        self.change_y = 0
        self.rect.y = 485
        self.frame_since_collision = 0
```

Here is the player's class. Most of the (def update) in the player's class are sprite collides commands.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite): 

# -- Attributes 
# Set speed vector of player
change_x = 0
change_y = 0

# Set to true if it is ok to jump
jump_ok = True

# Moving Platform determining if player is on the moving platform
movingPlatform_list = None

# Frames
frame = 0

# Count of frames since the player 
# collided against something. Used to prevent jumping
# when we haven't hit anything.
frame_since_collision = 0

# -- Methods 
# Constructor function 
def __init__(self, x, y): 
    # Call the parent's constructor 
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

    # List that the cat images will be saved in.
    self.images=[]
    # Load all the cat images, from cat1.png to cat8.png.
    for i in range(1,9):
        img = pygame.image.load("cat"+str(i)+".png").convert()
        img.set_colorkey(white)
        self.images.append(img)

    # By default, use image 0
    self.image = self.images[0]

    # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
    # image.
    # Update the position of this object by setting the values 
    # of rect.x and rect.y

    # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location. 
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y

# Change the speed of the player
def changespeed(self,x,y):
    self.change_x+=x
    self.change_y+=y

# Find a new position for the player 
def update(self, blocks, tables, chairLeft, chairRight, carMode): 

    # Move left/right
    self.rect.x += self.change_x

    # If we are moving right to left
    if self.change_x < 0:
        # Update our frame counter
        self.frame += 1

        # We go from 0...3. If we are above image 3, reset to 0
        # Multiply by 4 because we flip the image every 4 frames
        if self.frame > 3*4:
            self.frame = 0

        # Grab the image, do floor division by 4 because we flip
        # every 4 frames. 
        # Frames 0...3 -> image[0]
        # Frames 4...7 -> image[1]
        # etc.
        self.image = self.images[self.frame//4]

    # Move left to right. About the same as before, but use
    # images 4...7 instead of 0...3. Note that we add 4 in the last
    # line to do this.
    if self.change_x > 0:
        self.frame += 1
        if self.frame > 3*4:
            self.frame = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.frame//4+4]

    # See if we hit anything
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)
    movingPlatform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, movingPlatform_list, False)
    table_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, table_list, False)
    chairLeft_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, chairLeft_list, False)
    chairRight_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, chairRight_list, False)
    computerBlock_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, computerBlock_list, False)
    shooter_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, shooter_list, False)
    explosion_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, explosion_list, False)
    door_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, door_list, False)

    for block in block_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = block.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = block.rect.right

    for movingPlatform in movingPlatform_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = movingPlatform.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = movingPlatform.rect.right

    for table in table_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = table.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = table.rect.right

    for chairLeft in chairLeft_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = chairLeft.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = chairLeft.rect.right

    for chairRight in chairRight_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = chairRight.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = chairRight.rect.right

    for shooter in shooter_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = shooter.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = shooter.rect.right

    for explosion in explosion_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = explosion.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = explosion.rect.right

    for computerBlock in computerBlock_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = computerBlock.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = computerBlock.rect.right

    for door in door_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = door.rect.left
        else:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = door.rect.right

    # Move up/down
    self.rect.y += self.change_y

    # Check and see if we hit anything
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, blocks, False)
    movingPlatform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, movingPlatform_list, False)
    table_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, table_list, False)
    chairRight_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, chairRight_list, False)
    chairLeft_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, chairLeft_list, False)
    computerBlock_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, computerBlock_list, False)
    shooter_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, shooter_list, False)
    explosion_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, explosion_list, False)
    door_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, door_list, False)

    for block in block_hit_list:

        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
        else:
            self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

    # If we haven't hit anything in a while, allow us jump
    if self.frame_since_collision > 10:
        self.jump_ok = False

    for movingPlatform in movingPlatform_hit_list:

        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = movingPlatform.rect.top
        else:
            self.rect.top = movingPlatform.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

        self.rect.x += movingPlatform.change_x

    # Increment frame counter
    self.frame_since_collision += 1

    for table in table_hit_list:
        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = table.rect.top 
        else:
            self.rect.top = table.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

    # Increment frame counter
    self.frame_since_collision += 1

    for chairLeft in chairLeft_hit_list:
        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = chairLeft.rect.top 
        else:
            self.rect.top = chairLeft.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

    # Increment frame counter
    self.frame_since_collision += 1

    for chairRight in chairRight_hit_list:
        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = chairRight.rect.top 
        else:
            self.rect.top = chairRight.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

    # Increment frame counter
    self.frame_since_collision += 1

    for shooter in shooter_hit_list:
        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = shooter.rect.top 
        else:
            self.rect.top = shooter.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

    # Increment frame counter
    self.frame_since_collision += 1

    for explosion in explosion_hit_list:
        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = explosion.rect.top 
        else:
            self.rect.top = explosion.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

    for computerBlock in computerBlock_hit_list:

        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = computerBlock.rect.top
        else:
            self.rect.top = computerBlock.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

     # Increment frame counter
    self.frame_since_collision += 1

    for door in door_hit_list:

        # We hit something below us. Set the boolean to flag that we can jump
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.jump_ok = True

        # Keep track of the last time we hit something
        self.frame_since_collision = 0

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = door.rect.top
        else:
            self.rect.top = door.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

     # Increment frame counter
    self.frame_since_collision += 1

# Calculate effect of gravity.
def calc_grav(self):
    self.change_y += .35

    # See if we are on the ground.
    if self.rect.y >= 460 and self.change_y >= 0:
        self.change_y = 0
        self.rect.y = 460
        self.frame_since_collision = 0
        self.jump_ok = True

# Called when user hits 'jump' button
def jump(self,blocks):

    # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
    if self.jump_ok:
        self.change_y = -8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

When the player touches the car, set a different image for the player. Then change it back with another button. When you only change the image the controls will remain the same.